# Change of large symbol font breaks underbrace

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, libertine

I use Libertine for the main font and need to typeset a sum.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i = \underbrace{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}_{\text{3 things}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

I dislike the summation sign from `newtxmath` and would like to swap it out for the one from Computer Modern, using

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
```

but this breaks the underbrace:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just change the single symbol which was disturbing you. This could look like:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n} % note: you have to take another name than "largesymbols" here, as we do not want to redefine the whole thing.
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i = \underbrace{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}_{\text{3 things}}
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @soapygopher glad to hear that.